# C# Access to a generic class member whose type is a generic argument type, only via an interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, member

I have a generic class who holds a member whose type is an argument type.
I want to be able to access this member only by one of the interface it implements.
The reason I want to access the member only via this interface, instead of enumerating all the concrete types it could be, is because there are a great number of those types.

So concretely I want to find an equivalent of line 61 in that code (it is a compilation error):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

/* Interfaces */
public interface IArgumentClass
{
    void IArgumentClassMethod();
}
public interface ISpecialArgumentClass
{
    void ISpecialArgumentClassMethod();
}
public interface IContainerClass
{
    void IContainerClassClassMethod();
}

/* Argument types */
public class ArgumentClass0 : IArgumentClass
{
    public void IArgumentClassMethod(){}
}
public class SpecialArgumentClass0 : IArgumentClass, ISpecialArgumentClass
{
    public void IArgumentClassMethod(){}
    public void ISpecialArgumentClassMethod(){}
}
public class SpecialArgumentClass1 : IArgumentClass, ISpecialArgumentClass
{
    public void IArgumentClassMethod() { }
    public void ISpecialArgumentClassMethod() { }
}

/* Container types */
public class GenericContainer<T> : IContainerClass
    where T : IArgumentClass, new()
{
    public T t = new T();
    public void IContainerClassClassMethod() { }
}
public class NonGenericContainer : IContainerClass
{
    public void IContainerClassClassMethod(){}
}

/* main program */
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Instantiate
        IContainerClass[] containers = 
        {
            new GenericContainer<ArgumentClass0>(),
            new GenericContainer<SpecialArgumentClass0>(),
            new GenericContainer<SpecialArgumentClass1>(),
            new NonGenericContainer()
        };

        // We want to call IContainerClassClassMethod methods on all instances:
        foreach (IContainerClass container in containers)
            container.IContainerClassClassMethod();

        // We want to call ISpecialArgumentClassMethod on instances where it's possible:
        foreach (IContainerClass container in containers)
        {
            if (container.GetType().IsGenericType && container.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericContainer<>))
            {
                foreach (Type typeArgument in container.GetType().GetGenericArguments())
                {
                    if (typeArgument.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISpecialArgumentClass)))
                    {
                        // Next line is a compilation error. How can I get a similar result?
                        GenericContainer<ISpecialArgumentClass> mySpecializedClassWithSpecialArgument = container as GenericContainer<ISpecialArgumentClass>;
                        mySpecializedClassWithSpecialArgument.t.ISpecialArgumentClassMethod();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

*Note: You can fork and edit the code [here](http://ideone.com/kUnIqp).*

Comment: There's quite a lot of code here, would it be possible to reduce it to a much smaller example which contains what you want to do?

Comment: Please simplify (and shorten) your code. Also, tell us what the compilation error is. I know we can find out, but you might consider making it easy for us.

Comment: I edited the code to make it simpler (while keeping the minimum constraints, and the goal I am targetting). The compilation error is [CS0311](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384252.aspx) : I cannot use the type `ISpecialArgumentClass` as a parameter of `GenericContainer<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution is to just cast it to dynamic - you know it has a `t` field, so this should be safe to do.

```
if (typeArgument.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISpecialArgumentClass)))
{
    dynamic mySpecializedClassWithSpecialArgument =
        mySpecializedClass as dynamic;

    ISpecialArgumentClass specialArgumentClass = mySpecializedClassWithSpecialArgument.t;

    Console.WriteLine(specialArgumentClass.GetSpecialString());
}
```

### Note

I tried to edit it in ideone, but it would not compile. I suspect it's targeting an older version of .NET - dynamic was introduced in .NET 4 (VS 2010). However, I've tested the code in 2013 and it works.

Comment: Indeed, this [does not seem to work in Ideone](http://ideone.com/zPyMfN). According to the pop-up in the "choose language" menu, they use `C# (mono-2.8)`. However I tested your suggestion in my project environment (.Net 4.5 & VS2012) and it worked. Thanks for teaching me about the `dynamic` keyword and for a solution with minimum changes to my codebase.

Answer (score 2):

You get the compilation error because `ISpecialArgumentClass` is not of type `IArgumentClass`, but your `GenericClass` requires exactly this.

To solve this, you could introduce an empty interface which serves as base for both argument classes:

First, modify your interface declaration like this:

```
public interface IArgumentClassBase
{
}

public interface IArgumentClass : IArgumentClassBase
{
    String GetNormalString();
}

public interface ISpecialArgumentClass : IArgumentClassBase
{
    String GetSpecialString();
}
```

... then modify your generic class declaration like so:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IContainerClass
    where T : IArgumentClassBase, new()
```

Then the rest of your code should work...

Comment: So then how do I cast my `container` object's `t` member so that I can access its `ISpecialArgumentClassMethod()` method? When trying to compile the [code with the editions you suggested](http://ideone.com/EMlI1q) I still get a compilation error [CS0310](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h7h44y.aspx): 'ISpecialArgumentClass' must be a non-abstract type at line 61.

Comment: Indeed my proposal doesn't compile. Sorry for leading you down an incorrect path! I had to think about the code for a while, before I found the problem, which is in line 41: `new T()` can NEVER work for interfaces, simply because interfaces cannot have a c'tor. So strong typing is impossible here - in other words: RB's answer is the correct one...